# trouble with repeating rows when joining tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query to try and pull each dependent an employee has. But no matter how I join these tables, the query is repeating each employees dependent two or three times. So if for example, I have 1 child and a spouse dependent, when I run the query I would get two rows for my child and two rows for my spouse.  What can I do to be able to only get each dependent once and not have them repeat? I tried to group them by EmpID but was unsuccessful.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.DBdependent.EmpTableID, 
    dbo.DBdependent.Relation, 
    dbo.DBdependent.SSN AS DepSSN, 
    dbo.DBdependent.DOB, 
    dbo.DBdependent.Name, 
    dbo.DBEmployee.EmpID, 
    dbo.DBEmployee.FName, 
    dbo.DBEmployee.LName, 
    dbo.DBEmployee.SSN, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.HLTH, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.DNTL, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.VSN, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.LINS, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.LGLPLN, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.IDSHLD, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.ACCDNT, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.CNCR, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.HPIND, 
    dbo.DBdepElections.CRTCIL
FROM 
    dbo.DBdependent 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.DBdepElections ON dbo.DBdependent.EmpTableID = dbo.DBdepElections.EmpTableID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.DBEmployee ON dbo.DBdependent.EmpTableID = dbo.DBEmployee.ID
```

Comment: Use DISTINCT to remove dupes.  Without knowing your tables or data, thats basically all we can offer.

Comment: Step #1)  Read [ask].  Step #2) show table structure with sample data and output.

Comment: don't mix left and right joins. This usually cause errors...  Start with  dbo.DBEmployee and left join to it.

Comment: @dfundako.  Bad advice.  Fix the joins to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it's hard to tell based off your questions but try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    d.EmpTableID, 
    d.Relation, 
    d.SSN AS DepSSN, 
    d.DOB, 
    d.Name, 
    e.EmpID, 
    e.FName, 
    e.LName, 
    e.SSN, 
    el.HLTH, 
    el.DNTL, 
    el.VSN, 
    el.LINS, 
    el.LGLPLN, 
    el.IDSHLD, 
    el.ACCDNT, 
    el.CNCR, 
    el.HPIND, 
    el.CRTCIL
FROM 
    DBEmployee e
    LEFT JOIN
        DBdependent d ON d.EmpTableID = e.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.DBdepElections el ON d.EmpTableID = el.EmpTableID
```